# Correct way to return value to view from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have the following Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new ShippingCalculatorModel();
            model.carriers.AddRange(new[] { "Fedex", "Usps", "Ups" });
            return View(model);
        }  
   public double GetQuote(string carrierName)
        {               
            ICarrier carrier = null;
            var company = new Comapny();
            switch (carrierName)
            {
                case "Fedex":
                    carrier = new Fedex();
                    break;
                case "Usps":
                    carrier = new USPS();
                    break;
                case "Ups":
                    carrier = new UPS();
                    break;
                default:
                    carrier = new Null();
                    break;
            }
            company.SetCarrier(carrier);
            return company.GetQuote();
        }
```

List of carriers (Fedex, Usps, Ups) is shown in the listbox like this(index view):

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("GetQuote","ShippingCalculator", FormMethod.Get))
{ 
@Html.ListBox("carrierName", new SelectList(Model.carriers)) <!--I want to show quote after button click HERE -->
    <button type="submit">Get Quote</button>
}
```

How do I show Quote next to the dropdown list without going to a different View? I mean, on the same index page. I'm looking for best practicies on how to do it.

Comment: You do not need a form for this. Write a JavaScript (jQuery) function for your button click that will return the data by ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Early loading i.e. load carrier and quote in Index method and return the viewModel to the view. Good if you have few options.

Option 2: On demand loading i.e. display only carrier initially. On selection of a item in list, send a AJAX call to fetch the quote and display it. This option is good if you have big list of items and loading all quotes at once slows down the first response.

The choice depends on your UI/UX Design.

To accomplish option 1, you just need to prepare a viewModel object that will contain a list of carrier with quote details. Something like this will work:

```
Dictionary<string, Quote>
```

To accomplish option 2, as Peter suggested in comment, you will need to write a JavaScript function that will be called on list item click event. In this method you can grab the selected list item and send it in into a AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to

```
public JsonResult GetQuote(string carrierName)
{
  ICarrier carrier = null;
  ....
  company.SetCarrier(carrier);
  return Json(company.GetQuote(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then in the view

```
@Html.ListBox("carrierName", new SelectList(Model.carriers))
<div id="quote"></div>
<button type="button" id="getquote">Get Quote</button> // note type="button"

<script>
  var url = '@Url.Action("GetQuote")';
  $('#getquote').click(function() {
    var carrier = $('#carrierName').val();
    $.getJSON(url, { carrierName: carrier }, function(result) {
      $('#quote').text(response);
    });
  });    
</script>
```